# How to load a page to another page with angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I've written about that function. But function `successCallback` does not work!
It empty html, but can not load response.
In fact, the page is loaded but `html($compile(response)($scope))` does not work
how to load response in page?

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $compile) {
  $scope.myFunction = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/test-js.bc',
      data: {
        EndCityID: $(".EndCityID").val()
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $(".airlinename").empty().html($compile(response)($scope));
      },
      function errorCallback(response) {});
  }
});
```

Comment: have you considered AngularJS approach with `ng-include`?

Comment: no, I used ng-click ;When my function runs I load that page but it does not work !What should I use?

Comment: perhaps you need to work with [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize): scope your result `$scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(response);`, and compile it with `<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>`. Don't forget to import the script and inject the module: `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);`